# Supporting multiple screen sizes for android 4 and above in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have designed an app without following layouts

```
layout-sw320dp
layout-sw480dp
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw720dp
```

and drawable as

```
drawable-sw320dp
drawable-sw480dp
drawable-sw600dp
drawable-sw720dp
```

Here screen looks differently for galaxy nexus and nexus 7 but both support sw320dp only.
How will i make the app support for all screen sizes for android version 4 and above only.What are all layout and drawable that are needs to be specified to support all the screen sizes. this is my first app kindly help.

layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/back"
tools:context="com.example.ethernetvoicedemoapp.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:text="@string/scene1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
     android:textAllCaps="false"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:text="@string/scene3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
     android:textAllCaps="false"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:text="@string/scene5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:text="@string/off" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
     android:textAllCaps="false"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:text="@string/scene2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
     android:textAllCaps="false"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:text="@string/scene4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
     android:textAllCaps="false"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:text="@string/scene6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="139dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:text="@string/on"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

   <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/mic"
    android:src="@drawable/mic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/tap"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="@string/control"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what could be the answer to this problem.any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because your layout is perfect on the basis of density but both the phones have different screen sizes.

Instead of using different layouts you can dynamically change the layout params as per the Screen Size(width and height) using class DisplayMetrics

Without seeing the layout I cannot help more than this.

Comment: we can change the layout params but how about the placement of the buttons.i want it to be the same in both

Comment: You can make one layout using LinearLayout and weights. In this way your layout will remain same for all screen sizes and densities

Comment: I am asking about placement of each images. How should i do if i want the buttons arranged in a circular form